# How to make Skype ring on all connected devices?

Tags: skype

I've heard that Skype has a "feature" where if you are connected on multiple devices and someone calls you, it guesses which device it thinks you are closest to, and then only that one device rings. [Here's one example discussion of it, with no clean resolution](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Ring-on-all-devices/td-p/3484599).

So for example, if you're Skype-chatting to someone on your computer, then you pop outside, and someone calls you, Skype on the phone in your pocket won't ring because Skype has guessed that you are closest to your computer, so you won't receive the call.

I want to turn this feature off. I want Skype to behave like, say, Gmail, which pops up notifications on all connected devices then removes them when one device answers the mail, or like a 90s-style home landline with multiple phones in different rooms, where all phones ring until one is answered.

Is this possible?

Comment: You actually want this to happen?  Are you sure?  Of course the notion that Skype knows where you are is ridiculous ( no offense, a program, can't know where you are ).  The reason all your devices are not ringing are for some other reason.  *As of yesterday, all my devices running the current version of Skype ( more then 5 devices) all ring for me.*  Its extremely annoying.

Comment: Yes, I definitely want this to happen (and I wouldn't log in to skype on 5 devices). If I'm doing skype chat on a computer and step away for 5 minutes, I want my phone to ring

Comment: I can confirm the behavior, and would like an answer too. Skype will not ring my phone unless I sign off my computer.